# Is better if statements with multiple conditions or more else if statements?

Tags: r, if-statement, runtime

I'm mathematician so I don't know much about IT stuff. And I want to know if is faster to use  statements with multiple conditions or more if/else if statements like in example below. 
Consider I have really big data table (with millions of rows) and have this *if statements* in function which I apply to each row of one column and the result is stored in new column. And I just want to find out if there is some difference (faster/slower/same) between this two approaches.

```
    if (is.na(numerator) == TRUE){
        result = 0
    }  else if (numerator == 0){
        result = 0
    }  else if (is.na(denominator) == TRUE){
        result = max
    }  else if (denominator == 0){
        result = max
    }  else {
        result = numerator/denominator
    }
```

OR

```
    if (is.na(numerator) == TRUE || numerator == 0){
        result = 0
    }  else if (is.na(denominator) == TRUE || denominator == 0){
        result = max
    }  else {
        result = numerator/denominator
    }
```

Comment: Logically, the two versions are the same, and I also don't expect that performance would differ by much.  I say this because for a given set of conditions, the same number of logical checks would need to be run in either version.  So...use the version which you find more readable.  I would go with the second version, because each `result` outcome is bucketed together with all conditions which lead to that result.

Comment: For starters no need to do `is.na(numerator) == TRUE` , `is.na(numerator)` already returns TRUE/FALSE values.

Comment: Ok, thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Perhaps `match` and `%in%` would be applicable here?

Comment: Hey, there are two answers. And two standpoints are different.So which one or no one catch your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a simple experiment !

#### Dummy data

```
data <- data.frame(numerator = sample(c(0:9, NA), 10000, replace = T),
                   denominator = sample(c(0:9, NA), 10000, replace = T))
```

#### Two functions made up of two " if " conditions

```
f1 <- function(x){
  num <- x[1] ; denom <- x[2]
  if (is.na(num)){
    result = 0
  }  else if (num == 0){
    result = 0
  }  else if (is.na(denom)){
    result = Inf
  }  else if (denom == 0){
    result = Inf
  }  else {
    result = num / denom
  }
  return(result)
}

f2 <- function(x){
  num <- x[1] ; denom <- x[2]
  if (is.na(num) || num == 0){
    result = 0
  }  else if (is.na(denom) || denom == 0){
    result = Inf
  }  else {
    result = num / denom
  }
  return(result)
}
```

#### Benchmark analysis

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

res <- microbenchmark(
  type1 = {
    quotient1 <- apply(data, 1, f1)
  }, type2 = {
    quotient2 <- apply(data, 1, f2)
  }, times = 100
)

res
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max
# type1 21.91925 23.70445 27.16314 25.52339 26.90110 122.91710
# type2 22.00139 23.64297 26.11080 25.04576 26.46136  42.62506

autoplot(res)
```

[image]

#### Conclusion

You can try the benchmark several times and you can find that
there is no significant difference between two `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

to improve the code form above I would suggest you to take that if statement at first which will occur the most. This will speed the code a bit up because in the most cases the if else area hasn´t to be checked till the end. I did a very small test on this:

```
df <- data.frame(check = sample(c(0,1),size = 10000, replace = T, prob = c(0.1,0.9)),
                 solution = rep(NA, 10000))

start_t <- Sys.time()
for (idx in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if(df[idx, "check"]==0) {
    df[idx, "solution"] <- "zero"
  } else if (df[idx, "check"]==1) {
    df[idx, "solution"] <- "one"
  }
}
print(Sys.time()-start_t)
```

This code needs on my system `Time difference of 0.7524531 secs`. You can see that more ones than zeros will occur in the data frame. Hence I will switch the checking statements and will set "if check == 1" at the beginning.

```
df <- data.frame(check = sample(c(0,1),size = 10000, replace = T, prob = c(0.1,0.9)),
                 solution = rep(NA, 10000))

start_t <- Sys.time()
for (idx in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if(df[idx, "check"]==1) {
    df[idx, "solution"] <- "one"
  } else if (df[idx, "check"]==0) {
    df[idx, "solution"] <- "zero"
  }
}
print(Sys.time()-start_t)
```

This code needs only `Time difference of 0.6977119 secs`. It is ~8% faster and do the same job as the above example. Hope you got my point and good luck with your code.